# Android SYNCHRONIZATION with SQL mgmt studio using JSON

Tags: android

I am creating project for hotel to take orders in android.
In that i have to synchronize data(i am here using web-service for generating results) of sqlite of (tablet) and sqlstudio 2008 which is on server.
I am using json for it. But i want to know how to do it in Eclipse.Here is that code which is used to call web service.and while debuging it with TABLET it is showing me Error of PROCESS STOP UNEXPECTEDLY(android.process.acore)

```
public class JSONServices {
    public static final Boolean CallService = true;
    JSONHelper json = new JSONHelper();
    public String MissedQueriesCount = "0";

    // Function to Login A User
    public SW_Login Login(String UserId, String Password) {
        SW_Login loginwrapper = new SW_Login();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
            jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.Login(UserId, Password));
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{\"Service\":\"Login\",\"ResultSet\":[{\"Status\":\"1\",\"UserId\":\"21\",\"Token\":\"VJgueUxYCNaN6JGk\",\"Errorcode\":\"\",\"Errordesc\":\"\"}]}";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");

        loginwrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", 0);
        loginwrapper.UserId = GetJSONElement(retData, "UserId", 0);
        loginwrapper.Token = GetJSONElement(retData, "Token", 0);
        loginwrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode", 0);
        loginwrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc", 0);
        return loginwrapper;
    }

    // Function to Get Tables
    public List<SW_Table> GetTables(String AreaId) {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
            if (AreaId == "0") {
                String strURL = JSONServiceURL.GetAllOpenOrderTables();
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(strURL);
            } else {
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.GetTables(AreaId));
            }
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"gettables\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"AreaID\": 1, \"TableID\": 2, \"TableDesc\": \"Table 1\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"AreaID\": 1, \"TableID\": 4, \"TableDesc\": \"Table 1\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_Table> tablewrappers = new ArrayList<SW_Table>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_Table tablewrapper = new SW_Table();
                tablewrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                tablewrapper.AreaID = GetJSONElement(retData, "AreaID", counter);
                tablewrapper.TableID = GetJSONElement(retData, "TableID",
                        counter);
                tablewrapper.TableDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "TableDesc",
                        counter);
                tablewrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",
                        counter);
                tablewrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",
                        counter);
                tablewrappers.add(tablewrapper);
            }
        }
        return tablewrappers;
    }

    // Function to Get Order Details
    public List<SW_OrderDetails> GetOrderDetails(String Mode, String TableName) {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
            jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.GetOrderDetails(Mode,
                    TableName));
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"getorderdetails\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"OrderID\": 7, \"OrderDevice\": \"Reception\", \"OrderIP\": \"\", \"OrderTable\": \"Table 1_1\", \"OrderDate\": \"\", \"OrderStatus\": null, \"SendPing\": \"\", \"PaymentMode\": \"\", \"CreditNumber\": \"\", \"DebitNumber\": \"\", \"CancellationReason\": \"\", \"OrderNo\": 0, \"OrderAmount\": 50.0, \"CustId\": 0, \"OrderItems\": [ { \"OrderID\": 7, \"ItemID\": 405, \"Quantity\": 2.0, \"Remarks\": \"Cold\", \"Price\": 15.0, \"Discount\": 0.0, \"SaleTax\": 0.0, \"ItemName\": \"Coffee\", \"ItemTypeId\": 47 } ], \"Status\": \"S1\", \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_OrderDetails> orderwrappers = new ArrayList<SW_OrderDetails>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_OrderDetails orderwrapper = new SW_OrderDetails();
                orderwrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                orderwrapper.OrderID = GetJSONElement(retData, "OrderID",
                        counter);
                orderwrapper.OrderTable = GetJSONElement(retData, "OrderTable",
                        counter);
                orderwrapper.OrderStatus = GetJSONElement(retData,
                        "OrderStatus", counter);
                orderwrapper.OrderAmount = GetJSONElement(retData,
                        "OrderAmount", counter);
                orderwrapper.ItemTypeId = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeId",
                        counter);
                JSONArray retItemData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "OrderItems");
                for (int itemcounter = 0; itemcounter <= retItemData.length() - 1; itemcounter++) {
                    SW_ItemDetails itemwrapper = new SW_ItemDetails();
                    itemwrapper.ItemID = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemID",
                            counter);
                    itemwrapper.ItemName = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemName",
                            counter);
                    itemwrapper.Quantity = GetJSONElement(retData, "Quantity",
                            counter);
                    itemwrapper.Remarks = GetJSONElement(retData, "Remarks",
                            counter);
                    orderwrapper.ItemDetails.add(itemwrapper);
                }

                orderwrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",
                        counter);
                orderwrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",
                        counter);
                orderwrappers.add(orderwrapper);
            }
        }
        return orderwrappers;
    }

    // Function to Get Order Details
    public List<SW_ItemDetails> GetTableOrderDetails(String Mode, String TableId) {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
            jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.GetTableOrderDetails(
                    Mode, TableId));
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"gettableorder\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"OrderID\": 3, \"ItemID\": 403, \"Quantity\": 1, \"Remarks\": \"\", \"Price\": 35.0, \"Discount\": 0.0, \"SaleTax\": 0.0, \"ItemName\": \"Hot Chocolate\", \"ItemTypeId\": 47, \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"OrderID\": 3, \"ItemID\": 405, \"Quantity\": 2, \"Remarks\": \"Cold\", \"Price\": 15.0, \"Discount\": 0.0, \"SaleTax\": 0.0, \"ItemName\": \"Coffee\", \"ItemTypeId\": 47, \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_ItemDetails> itemDetails = new ArrayList<SW_ItemDetails>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            SW_ItemDetails itemwrappertemp = new SW_ItemDetails();
            itemwrappertemp.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", 0);
            if (itemwrappertemp.Status.toString().trim().equals("0")) {
                return null;
            }
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_ItemDetails itemwrapper = new SW_ItemDetails();
                itemwrapper.ItemID = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemID", counter);
                itemwrapper.ItemName = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemName",
                        counter);
                itemwrapper.Quantity = GetJSONElement(retData, "Quantity",
                        counter);
                itemwrapper.Remarks = GetJSONElement(retData, "Remarks",
                        counter);
                itemwrapper.ItemTypeId = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeId",
                        counter);
                itemwrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                itemwrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",
                        counter);
                itemwrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",
                        counter);
                itemDetails.add(itemwrapper);
            }
        }
        return itemDetails;
    }

    public void SaveOrder(String TableId, List<JSONObject> jsonarray) {
        try {

            Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
            kvPairs.put("orderdetails", jsonarray.toString());
            // Normally I would pass two more JSONObjects.....
            if (CallService == true) {
                HttpResponse re = json.doPost(JSONServiceURL
                        .SaveOrderDetails(TableId.toString().trim()), kvPairs);
                String temp = EntityUtils.toString(re.getEntity());
                if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS") == 0) {
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "Sending complete!",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else // For Test Purpose
            {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Function to Get Areas
    public List<SW_Area> GetAreas() {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.SyscArea());
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"syncarea\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"AreaId\": 1, \"AreaDesc\": \"Area 1\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"AreaId\": 2, \"AreaDesc\": \"Area 2\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"AreaId\": 3, \"AreaDesc\": \"Area 3\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_Area> areawrappers = new ArrayList<SW_Area>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_Area areawrapper = new SW_Area();
                areawrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                areawrapper.AreaID = GetJSONElement(retData, "AreaId", counter);
                areawrapper.AreaDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "AreaDesc",
                        counter);
                areawrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",
                        counter);
                areawrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",
                        counter);
                areawrappers.add(areawrapper);
            }
        }
        return areawrappers;
    }
    // Function to Get Table
    public List<SW_Table> GetTables() {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.SyncTable());
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"synctable\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"AreaId\": 1, \"TableId\":1.1 , \"TableDesc\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"AreaId\": 2, \"TableId\":2.1\": \"TableDesc\":null,\"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null }, { \"AreaId\": 3, \"TableId\":2.1\"TableDesc\": 3\", \"Status\": null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_Table> areawrappers = new ArrayList<SW_Table>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_Table areawrapper = new SW_Table();
                areawrapper.Status = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                areawrapper.AreaID = GetJSONElement(retData, "AreaId", counter);
                areawrapper.TableID = GetJSONElement(retData, "TableID",
                        counter);
                areawrapper.TableDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "TableDesc",
                        counter);
                areawrapper.ErrCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",
                        counter);
                areawrapper.ErrDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",
                        counter);
                areawrappers.add(areawrapper);
            }
        }
        return areawrappers;
    }
    // Function to Get ItemType
    public List<SW_ItemType> GetItemTypes() {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.SyncItemType());
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"syncitemtype\", \"ResultSet\": [ {\"Status\":null, \"ItemTypeId\": 1, \"ItemTypeName\":Cold Drinks \"ItemTypeDesc\": null, \"ItemTypeCode\": null, \"Discount\":30,\"SalesTax\":12.50,\"Flag\":null,\"ImageIndex\":null,\"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null },{\"Status\":null,\"ItemTypeId\": 2, \"ItemTypeName\":MainCourse,\"ItemTypeDesc\": null, \"ItemTypeCode\": null, \"Discount\":25,\"SalesTax\":12.50,\"Flag\":null,\"ImageIndex\":null,\"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_ItemType> areawrappers = new ArrayList<SW_ItemType>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_ItemType areawrapper  = new SW_ItemType();
                areawrapper.Status       = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemTypeId   = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeId", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemTypeName = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeName", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemTypeDesc = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeDesc", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemTypeCode = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeCode", counter);
                areawrapper.Discount     = GetJSONElement(retData, "Discount",counter);
                areawrapper.SalesTax     = GetJSONElement(retData, "SalesTax",counter);
                areawrapper.Flag         = GetJSONElement(retData, "Flag",counter);
                areawrapper.ImageIndex   = GetJSONElement(retData, "ImageIndex",counter);
                areawrapper.ErrCode      = GetJSONElement(retData, "ErrCode",counter);
                areawrapper.ErrDesc      = GetJSONElement(retData, "ErrDesc",counter);      

                areawrappers.add(areawrapper);
            }
        }
        return areawrappers;
    }
    // Function to Get Item
    public List<SW_Item> GetItems() {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        if (CallService == true) {
                jObject = json.getHttpJson(JSONServiceURL.SyscArea());
        } else // For Test Purpose
        {
            String jsonString = "{ \"ResFrom\": \"syncitem\", \"ResultSet\": [ { \"Status\": 1, \"ItemId\":1, \"ItemTypeId\":2,\"ItemName\":Jaljira,\"ItemDesc\":null,\"Price\":20,\"Active\":null,\"ItemCode\":null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null },{ \"Status\": 1, \"ItemId\":2, \"ItemTypeId\":3,\"ItemName\":NimbuPani,\"ItemDesc\":null,\"Price\":15,\"Active\":null,\"ItemCode\":null, \"Errorcode\": null, \"Errordesc\": null } ] }";
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        List<SW_Item> areawrappers = new ArrayList<SW_Item>();
        JSONArray retData = GetJSONArray(jObject, "ResultSet");
        if (retData != null) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= retData.length() - 1; counter++) {
                SW_Item areawrapper      = new SW_Item();
                areawrapper.Status       = GetJSONElement(retData, "Status", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemId       = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemId", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemTypeId   = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemTypeId",counter);
                areawrapper.ItemName     = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemName", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemDesc     = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemDesc", counter);
                areawrapper.Price        = GetJSONElement(retData, "Price", counter);
                areawrapper.Active       = GetJSONElement(retData, "Active", counter);
                areawrapper.ItemCode     = GetJSONElement(retData, "ItemCode", counter);                
                areawrapper.ErrCode      = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errorcode",counter);
                areawrapper.ErrDesc      = GetJSONElement(retData, "Errordesc",counter);

                areawrappers.add(areawrapper);
            }
        }
        return areawrappers;
    }






















    private String Encrypt(String password) {
        String toEnc = password; // Value to encrypt
        MessageDigest mdEnc = null;
        try {
            mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Encryption algorithm
        mdEnc.update(toEnc.getBytes(), 0, toEnc.length());
        String md5 = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(16);
        if (md5.length() < 32)
            md5 = "0" + md5;
        return md5;
    }

    /* **************************************** */
    /* Private Methods To Extract JSON Contents */
    /* **************************************** */

    private JSONArray GetJSONArray(JSONObject obj, String arrayName) {
        JSONArray retData = null;
        try {
            retData = obj.getJSONArray(arrayName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retData;
    }

    private String GetJSONElement(JSONArray jsonArr, String Element, int index) {
        String element = "";
        try {
            element = jsonArr.getJSONObject(index).getString(Element)
                    .toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return element;
    }

    private String GetJSONString(JSONObject jObj, String Element) {
        String element = "";
        try {
            element = jObj.getString(Element).toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return element;
    }

    private JSONObject GetJSONObject(JSONArray jsonArr, int index) {
        JSONObject retData = null;
        try {
            retData = jsonArr.getJSONObject(index);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retData;
    }
}
```